# Touchpad not working and does not appear in dconf-Editor

Tags: touchpad

I am running 19.10 (upgraded from 19.04 yesterday) and have noticed that my touchpad is not working under Ubuntu. It works in the login screen but not after Ubuntu has loaded.

I do not know if the upgrade caused this to happen as I usually use a bluetooth mouse but yesterday the battery in the mouse went and it was then I noticed the touchpad didn't work. I usually use Wayland but have switched to x11 to faultfind. Here is what I have tried so far:

I went to `org → gnome → settings-daemon → peripherals` but the touchpad doesn't appear there. So I installed xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and ran `synclient | grep Touchpad`this returned

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

As I have just installed the synaptics driver `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is already installed, I am at a bit of a loss as to what to do next.

EDIT: The laptop is a Tuxedo Book BC1707 Barebone N87xEZ. https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/de/Infos/News/BC1507-BC1707-ideal-fuer-alltaegliche-Arbeiten-und-den-professionellen-Einsatz.tuxedo

Comment: @K7AAY I have edited the question with the laptop model. It is a Linux only laptop made by the Tuxedo company in Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Settings-System(Geräte)-Mouse and Touchpad (Maus und Tastfeld) and enabled the Touchpad there. It is now working again.